# How to check any class is missing in Android?

Tags: java, android

My Android application depends on a jar file (says `api.jar`). And the `api.jar` itself depends on another jar `base.jar`. If I include the `api.jar` ONLY in my Android project, the project does compile and output apk file, but it will fail on runtime, because some classes available only in `base.jar` are not packaged into the apk.

For some reason, I can't use the maven alternative for these jar files and let Gradle resolve the dependencies for me. So the question is, how can I find out that any classes is missing during the build of my Android project?

It seems that there are some tools in Java world that may helps (like jdeps), but I don't have idea how to integrate them into my Android build.

Comment: In your source code editor do you recognize the above classes or not?

Comment: @maniaq When ctrl-click into the class with Android Studio, the missing classes in base.jar are not recognized by the IDE, but the compilation passes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not any problem when compiling ,this issue is related with the memory .Please do these steps 1-Clean project 2-Invalidate 3-Sync with file system 4-Sync project with gradle files 5-Close project then close android studio 6-Open android studio then open you project. I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to memory enable multidex = true in your gradle script.